# Facebook graph API to reply comments from a post

Tags: facebook

I have a php application that is designed to auto reply comments from a post. I've created the facebook developer app for my page and also subscribe to webhook. However, when i try to reply a comment from graph api explorer, it shows that i do not have permission(s): manage_pages,publish_pages. I understand that I would need add in the permission from "Permissions and Features". I do not have a website for my facebook page, how do get facebook to approve my request? I am the admin of the page, do i still need manage_pages, publish_pages permission?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

According to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v3.2/object/private_replies, you need `read_page_mailboxes` permission to be able to publish such private replies.

> I am the admin of the page, do i still need manage_pages, publish_pages permission?

`manage_pages` is the basic requirement for the API to *recognize* you as an admin of a page to begin with; without that permission, you would just be seen as a “normal” user with no administrative access to the page at all.